# C# наследование контрола

Tags: c#, winforms, наследование

Надо добавить к GroupBox ещё одну property как сделать клас со всем что есть у groupbox и добавить собственое свойство?

Comment: Выполнить банальное наследование, добавить свойство и переопределить необходимые методы? Класс не запечатан.

Comment: Как переопределить конструктор?

Comment: Объявить производный конструктор, затем вызвать конструктор базовго класса

Comment: Смотря для какой цели нужно дополнительное свойство. В некоторых случаях можно использовать свойство [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx), которое есть у всех контролов.